# Facebook application issue with callbackurl?

Tags: java, facebook, facebook-apps

In facebook application  i define

```
  Deauthorize Callback URL - http://www.domainname.com/3c/login/fblogin.xhtml
    Valid OAuth redirect URIs - http://www.domainname.com/3c/login/fblogin.xhtml
    -Site URL - http://www.domainname.com
```

now if someone access website like

```
http://domainname.com/3c
```

i am getting exception

```
Warning
Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration.: One or more of the given URLs is not allowed by the App's settings. It must match the Website URL or Canvas URL, or the domain must be a subdomain of one of the App's domains.
```

Any one know how to resolve this issue

Answer (score 1):

*domainname.com* is NOT *www.domainname.com*

If you have configured *www.domainname.com* as site URL then *domainname.com* is not allowed. If you do it the other way round it should work.

Comment: I want both should work so what i have to do for that?

Comment: Since www.domainname.com can technically be seen as a subdomain of domainname.com you have to specify the higher level domain.

Comment: So do u mean i have to specify `domainname.com` in facebook application and it will work for `www.domainname.com `